# Can't install snap after removing it

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core

I'm pretty new to snaps, so I didn't know if it was a bug or if I was missing something.

I installed a Snap via "**sudo snap install ubuntu-clock-app**" then I removed it via "**sudo snap remove ubuntu-clock-app**", because the app didn't want to start, now I tried to install it again to file a bug, but it says that it is already installed (it isn't)

```
error: can't install "ubuntu-clock-app": snap "ubuntu-clock-app" already installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you're having problems with this. Fortunately we released snapd 2.0.3 to xenial last week, so we should be able to get you back on track.

First, please update and make sure you're on 2.0.3; `dpkg -l snapd` should show you that version.

Next, let's clean up your snapd state, which has gotten into a mess. This deletes all snaps from your system and gets you back to an empty state: [zyga's reset-state script](https://github.com/zyga/devtools/blob/master/reset-state).

This fixes all known bugs, so let us know if you manage to break it again!

Comment: I think it fixed it for now, I'll let you know if I manage to break it again :D

Answer (score 3):

This smells rather like a bug to me. Do you mind opening it against the snapd package? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the snappy developers. I'm sorry you are bumping into errors. I'll try to help you out.

Can you pastebin two more things for me please?

```
$ mount | pastebinit
```

And then:

```
$ snap list | pastebinit
```

Thanks

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/16051600/ and https://paste.ubuntu.com/16051605/

Comment: No way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the

```
snap changes
```

command to see what went on. Then you can look at the details of the particular change set you're interested in (`ubuntu-clock-app`) with `snap changes $CHANGEID` to find out more.

You can also [learn more about snappy changes](http://blog.labix.org/2016/04/20/snappy-changes).

I believe you can also reset the state machine, but as it's a manual step and I'm not an expert on doing it, I'll leave it for the snappy developers to comment on :)

Comment: it's all on hold or Errors

Comment: Can you copy the output of running `snap changes` and `snap changes $CHANGEID` for the ubuntu-clock-app installation that fails? If you could then paste it on http://pastebin.ubuntu.com perhaps we can help you more debugging what happened and figuring out a fix. Thanks!

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16037546/ every other Id was just empty